# Как правильнее описывать сервисы с учетом MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, mvvm

Я раньше вообще всю логику плодил внутри сервиса, но перейдя на MVVM я начал делать вот так: делаю у сервиса события соответствующие вызываемым функциям контракта и вызываю их, а уже где то снаружи в модели создаю экземпляр сервиса, привязываюсь к этим событиям и обрабатываю их. Вот мне интересно насколько такой подход правильный? Именно в контексте MVVM как сделать корректно?

Comment: Расскажите поподробнее, как именно устроена ваша программа. Без этого никаких рекомендаций дать невозможно.

Comment: @VladD я же говорю есть WCF сервис. В нем например метод void Connect() и событие ClientConnected. При вызове клиентом этого метода он делает так: void Connect() => ClientConnected?.Invoke(). Но вообще вопрос не о том как я делаю, а о том как правильно делать?

Comment: Ну, а в чём смысл программы? Чистый сервис? А что в UI? Если UI нету, то MVVM не настолько и нужен.

Comment: @VladD UI есть.

Comment: Окей, тогда опишите, что именно делает программа. Ваше описание («есть WCF сервис. В нем например метод void Connect() и событие ClientConnected») не даёт информации, чтобы судить о правильности архитектуры.

Comment: @VladD да блин вопрос не о какой то конкретной программе, а в принципе о связке WCF и MVVM.

Comment: А принцип, на мой взгляд, простой: WCF — внутренняя часть модели.

Comment: @VladD сервис это и есть модель насколько я понимаю. Вопрос лишь в том как эту модель связать с ViewModel-ю.

Comment: Окей, кажется понял. написал ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрите.

Идеология MVVM заключается в том, что низкоуровневые штуки наподобие WCF сидят в модели и позволяют собой управлять *как им вздумается*. Никакого ограничения MVVM не накладывает. Например, если это WCF-сервис, вы можете иметь `event ClientConnected` и `event ClientDisconnected`, или там `ObservableCollction<Model.Client>`, или по-другому — как вам лично кажется удобнее.

Главное, чтобы нужные данные и сигналы об изменениях были *хоть каким-то образом* доступны. Например, так, чтобы ими могло воспользоваться консольное приложение.

А вот задача VM — подписаться на нужные event'ы, и выставить нужные данные таким образом, чтобы View ими могла пользоваться. Это означает, например, `ObservableCollection<ClientVM>` для изменяющегося списка клиентов.

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите сказать что в принципе я делаю правильно? А в ViewModel-и может быть какая то логика описана или это просто класс для биндинга? Ну вот хотя бы мне что надо по факту хранить параллельно два списка клиентов? Один внутри сервиса, а другой формировать во ViewModel-и по событиям? Т.е. внутри сервиса в списке будут модели в которые входят всякие там Callback-и клиентов и прочие касающиеся логики детали. А внутри ViewModel-и в списки будут модели в которые входят только свойства которые биндятся к таблице клиентов например.

Comment: @DarkByte: По идее, в том, что вы рассказали, ничего плохого нет. В VM должна быть логика, относящаяся к программе: запуститься, запустить сервис, показать UI, подписаться на изменения сервиса, принимать команды от пользователя и передавать их сервису и т. п. А логика самого сервиса принадлежит сервису.

Comment: @DarkByte: Да, довольно часто нужно два списка клиентов. VM-клиенту колбеки не нужны, зато нужно `INotifyPropertyChanged`. И WCF бежит в каком-то своём потоке, то есть модельный клиент бежит там же, а `ClientVM` должна бежать только в главном потоке.

Comment: а вот список клиентов который в ViewModel. Он будет состоять из объектов Model или ViewModel?

Comment: @DarkByte: Тот, который выставляется для Binding'а в UI — список `ViewModel`-ных объектов. UI вообще не должен видеть модель.

Comment: вот например решал недавно такую задачу: на сервере вводятся пределы и шаг интегрирования, пределы разбиваются на подзадачи, формируется очередь подзадач вида пределы и шаг, клиенты берут подзадачи из очереди, решают и снова берут пока она не опустеет, после чего выводится результат. Так вот вот эта логика разбиения на подзадачи и выдача клиентам их это должно было быть в сервисе? А то я сделал в ViewModel-и, наверное не правильно...

Comment: @DarkByte: Ну, сложно сказать. Я бы вынес в VM, поскольку это, судя по всему, основная логика программы.